# How to execute a operator secret code and receive data in stringbuffer?

Tags: android

How to execute a operator code  like `*12345#` and receive response data in stringbuffer ?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*12345*"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Thank you

Comment: For a lot of reasons, this will not work.

Comment: Plz can you gives me some reasons, thank you.

Comment: 1. Not all actions are designed to have a result. The documentation of `ACTION_CALL` states that is has no result. 2. The result, if any, is often dependent upon the implementation of the component that handles the action. 3. Regarding operator codes or alternative dial codes specifically, how do you actually know what dialing this code will do? I've dialed ADCs which redirect me to another (hidden) Activity on the device without actually dialing anything.